# No Method Error when using .sum to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sum, nomethoderror

The below function will throw a NoMethodError when it is expected to calculate the sum of a given array.

By printing the result "p" it should return 10.

```
p [1,2,3,4].sum
#=> 10
```

Instead of getting the result of the sum, I get the error below.

```
undefined method `sum' for [1, 2, 3, 4]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `sum` was added in Ruby 2.4, you're probably running an older version.

Comment: You can do [1,2,3,4].inject(:+)

Comment: According to which Ruby documentation? Are you 100% sure that the documentation you are reading is for your version of Ruby and not some other version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check what version of ruby you're using with `ruby -v`

If you have a version older than 2.4, you can use inject instead.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0,:+)
```

The above is a shorthand for

```
   [1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0) {|sum, value| sum + value}
```

The zero `0` is needed to handle empty arrays, which otherwise would return `nil`

Comment: You might want to pass a default value, i.e. `ary.inject(0, :+)` to account for empty arrays.

Comment: Thank you, it was a version problem I had 2.3.7, not 2.4.